# Custom WSDL en Axis2

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

Estoy haciendo los pasos para que en un proyecto Axis2 me respete el wsdl original que agrego en la carpeta META-INF, al ejecutarlo veo que el wsdl se va respetando, hasta cierto punto, luego ya se pierde el orden.

En el file.wsdl tengo:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://services.mdsp.huawei.com">      <wsdl:types></wsdl:types>
<wsdl:part name="getUserInfoResponse" element="impl:getUserInfoReturn">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="topupFromBSSNotifycation"><wsdl:part  name="topupFromBSSNotifycationRequest" element="impl:topupFromBSSNotifycation">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message   name="subscribeServiceReturn"><wsdl:part name="subscribeServiceResponse" element="impl:subscribeServiceReturn">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="RequestSOAPHeader">    <wsdl:part name="RequestSOAPHeader" element="impl:RequestSOAPHeader">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="addBonusResponse">    <wsdl:part name="addBonusResponse" element="impl:addBonusResponse">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="subscribeService"><wsdl:part name="subscribeServiceRequest" element="impl:subscribeService">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="getUserInfoReturn">
```

y cuando lo veo en el navegador "axis2/Servicio?wsdl" aparece de la siguiente forma

```
 <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://services.mdsp.huawei.com">  <wsdl:types></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="topupFromBSSNotifycation">       <wsdl:part name="topupFromBSSNotifycationRequest"   element="impl:topupFromBSSNotifycation">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="subscribeServiceReturn"><wsdl:part name="subscribeServiceResponse" element="impl:subscribeServiceReturn">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="RequestSOAPHeader"><wsdl:part name="RequestSOAPHeader" element="impl:RequestSOAPHeader">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="addBonusResponse"><wsdl:part name="addBonusResponse" element="impl:addBonusResponse">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="subscribeService"><wsdl:part name="subscribeServiceRequest" element="impl:subscribeService">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="getUserInfoReturn"><wsdl:part name="getUserInfoResponse" element="impl:getUserInfoReturn">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message>
```

No se si alguien ha tenido un problema parecido, pero necesito que el orden sea identico al archivo wsdl que tengo en el folder META-INF.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué orden es el que quieres conservar? No es muy claro en tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias por contestar, ejemplo, en el file.wsdl tengo:      </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="getUserInfo">
      <wsdl:part name="getUserInfoRequest" element="impl:getUserInfo"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   y cuando lo veo en el navegador "axis2/Servicio?wsdl" aparece de la siguiente forma   </wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="topupFromBSSNotifycation"><wsdl:part name="topupFromBSSNotifycationRequest" element="impl:topupFromBSSNotifycation">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message>

Comment: Procura añadir la información relevante a la pregunta editándola, que así es más fácil verla para todos. Esta vez te ayudé con eso. Sobre el fragmento que pones, a simple vista parecen dos mensajes diferentes. Creo que debes incluir los archivos completos